# How to convert string to custom object with Convert

Tags: c#

I found following statement in `Programming in C#` book:

> IFormattable provides the functionality to format the value of an object 
>       into a string representation. It is also used by the Convert class to do the opposite.

I have class:

```
class a : IFormattable
{
    private string aa = "123";
    private int bb = 5;

    public string ToString(string format, IFormatProvider formatProvider)
    {
        return $"aa={aa} bb={bb}" ;
    }
}
```

But how to convert string by using Convert into object of `a`?

UPD:
I know idea of parsing. But my question is how to use Convert class to create new object from string.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/capitalization-conventions

Comment: Opposite to converting to string is *parsing*. You would have to parse the string and construct new `a` object from it.

Comment: I'd question that programming book if I were you. The `IFormattable` interface is used only to convert an object to its string representation. From MSDN: `The IFormattable interface converts an object to its string representation based on a format string and a format provider.`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert string type to user defined custom type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3610067/how-to-convert-string-type-to-user-defined-custom-type)

Answer (score 2):

You could provide an [explicit conversion operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/using-conversion-operators):

```
public class A : IFormattable
{
    public string Aa { get; } = "123";
    public int Bb { get; } = 5;

    public A(){ }

    public A(string aa, int bb)
    {
        this.Aa = aa;
        this.Bb = bb;
    }

    public string ToString(string format, IFormatProvider formatProvider)
    {
        return $"aa={Aa} bb={Bb}";
    }

    public static explicit operator A(string strA)  
    {
        if (strA == null) return null;
        if (!strA.Contains("aa=") || !strA.Contains(" bb=")) return null;
        string[] parts = strA.Split(new[] {' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        if (parts.Length != 2 || !parts[0].StartsWith("aa=") || !parts[1].StartsWith("bb=")) return null;

        string aa = parts[0].Substring(3);
        string bb = parts[1].Substring(3);
        int bbInt;
        if (!int.TryParse(bb, out bbInt)) return null;
        A a = new A(aa, bbInt);
        return a;
    }
}
```

Sample:

```
A a = new A("987", 4711);
string toString = a.ToString(null, null);
a = (A) toString;
```

Answer (score 1):

**See Tims answer below.**

I see you want to convert a string to your custom type.
Of course, you need to explicitly define how this conversion takes place.

You can implement [implicit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/implicit) or [explicit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/explicit) cast operators:

```
public class A
{
   public static implicit operator string(A a)
   {
      // allows: 
      // var a = new A();
      // string x = a;
      return "A converted to string"; 
   } 

   public static explicit operator A(string s)
   {
      // allows: 
      // var s = "something";
      // var a = (A)s;
      return new A(); 
   } 
}
```

Note: you can use implicit and explicit conversion both ways. The reason I chose explicit for one and implicit for another, is just for demonstration purposes.

You could combine this with allowing [Convert.ChangeType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dtb69x08(v=vs.110).aspx). Under the hood, this casts your value to an IConvertible, and then uses a switch statement to call the correct conversion method. (see [reference source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/convert.cs)). Note that it uses the TypeCode, not the type, so it also works on Enums, and your own class if you implement the IConvertible.GetTypeCode method.
You could call it like this:

```
var d = (decimal)System.Convert.ChangeType("17.4", typeof(decimal));
```

You could make it a bit type safer by wrapping it like this:

```
static TTargetType ParseTo<TTargetType>(string target)
{
   return (TTargetType)System.Convert.ChangeType(target, typeof(TTargetType));
}
```

which you could use like this:

```
var d = ParseTo<decimal>("17.4");
```

But most of the time you're better if you just use the parse method of the type itself:

```
var d = decimal.Parse("17.4");
```